# Injecting mock Spring repository using Mockito results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test a class which has an autowired repository field.

```
@Component
public class DefaultRuleTester implements RuleTester {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(DefaultRuleTester.class);

    @Autowired
    RuleChainRepository ruleChainRepository;

    public DefaultRuleTester() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<ResultChain> test(Entity entity) {
        if (entity == null)
            return Collections.emptyList();
        try {
            return selectAndTestAllRuleChains(entity);
        } catch (InvalidClassException e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to select RuleChains from database.", e);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    protected List<ResultChain> selectAndTestAllRuleChains(Entity entity) throws InvalidClassException {
        Collection<RuleChain> ruleChains = selectRuleChainsFromConnection();
        return testRuleChains(entity, ruleChains);
    }

    private Collection selectRuleChainsFromConnection() throws InvalidClassException {
        Collection<RuleChain> ruleChains = ruleChainRepository.findAll();
        if (ruleChains == null)
            return Collections.emptyList();
        return ruleChains;
    }

    protected List<ResultChain> testRuleChains(Entity entity, Collection<RuleChain> ruleChains) {
        // business logic
    }
}
```

RuleChainRepository:

```
public interface RuleChainRepository extends JpaRepository<RuleChain, Long> {
}
```

I'm using Mockito to inject the repository into the CUT:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DefaultRuleTesterTest {

    private final Incident entity = new Incident();

    @InjectMocks
    private DefaultRuleTester tester;

    @Mock
    private RuleChainRepository ruleChainRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        tester = new DefaultRuleTester();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenEntityTested_shouldReturnGivenResultChains() {
        Mockito.when(ruleChainRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(singletonList(new RuleChainSpy()));
        List<ResultChain> resultChain = tester.test(entity);
        assert(1, resultChains.size());
    }
}
```

However running the test throws a NullPointerException, pointing at the `@Autowired` `ruleChainRepository`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.remsdaq.resque.officersubscription.entity_controller.DefaultRuleTester.selectRuleChainsFromConnection(DefaultRuleTester.java:30)
    at com.remsdaq.resque.officersubscription.entity_controller.DefaultRuleTester.selectAndTestAllRuleChains(DefaultRuleTester.java:25)
    at com.remsdaq.resque.officersubscription.entity_controller.DefaultRuleTester.test(DefaultRuleTester.java:17)
    at com.remsdaq.resque.officersubscription.entity_controller.DefaultRuleTesterTest.whenTested_shouldReturnGivenResultChains(DefaultRuleTesterTest.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I've tried using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in the test's set up instead of (and along-side `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`). I've also tried giving `RuleChainRepository` a `@Component` annotation.

I use the same set of annotations elsewhere to mock the same repository for other components, and I can't see any reasons why it isn't working here. Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Relevant section of pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) in combination with @MockBean if you are using spring ?

Comment: If you use MockitoJUnitRunner you have to wire the dependencies yourself, something like `tester = new DefaultRuleTester(ruleChainRepository)`

Comment: @Michal thanks for the suggestion, I will have a look at using this. I especially like the fact that you can `@Qualify` the mocked component specifically for the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem

```
 public void setUp() {
        tester = new DefaultRuleTester();
    }
```

Remove this piece of code.

You are doing `@InjectMocks` and then you are creating a new object. So tester object will not have repository mock injected.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm just wondering then why I was able to use `@InectMocks` in another test class where I'd instantiated the CUT? The set-up is almost identical.